# JSF: setting a property in a wizard form with multiple submit actions

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, javabeans

I have this scenario: in the first tab of a primefaces wizard component, I have some fields and a button. The button saves some data, does some business logic and, with the results, sets some properties of the form bean (which is in ViewScope) that are not related to a specific field of the form. I have checked that in the invoke application phase, the values are set properly.
In the second tab I have another button that has to do some business logic using the values set by the first one but, doing some debug, I noticed that the values, even if not related to any field of the form, are overwritten I think during the update model phase invoked when I click the second button.

How can I avoid this? Is there a way to obtain the correct behaviour?
I looked around but I couldn't find any example of a wizard form with multiple submissions. Thanks for help!

```
<p:wizard widgetVar="wiz" render="true" id="wizard" showNavBar="false">
    <p:tab id="step0" title="Step0" step="0">
        <!-- Some other fields-->
        <p:commandButton value="Save and do some business logic"
            action="#{formBean.save}"
            oncomplete="wiz.loadStep (wiz.cfg.steps [1], false)">
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="step1" title="Step1" step="1">
        <!-- Some other fields-->
        <p:commandButton value="Second button: use the previous informations"
            action="#{formBean.doSomething}"
            oncomplete="wiz.loadStep (wiz.cfg.steps [2], false)">
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:tab>
</p:wizard>
```

**Edit:**
To show an example I can say that my bean contains a business logic object. During the first submission, this object is being saved so the database (Mysql and Hibernate), assigns to it a progressive id.
During the second submission, when I try to read this id, the value is zero so, obviously, I get an error.

Something like:

```
public class FormBean{
      private BLObject object;
      // Constructor Getters and setters

      // Method executed during the first submission
      public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
          //Save the object and set his id
          PersistanceClass.getInstance().save(object);
      }

      // Method executed during the second submission
      public void doSomethingWhitTheId(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
          //Access the id... id=0 returned
          int id = object.getId();

      }
}
```

Comment: how about using the `exectue` attribute of the `p:commandButton ` like `<p:commandButton execute="mainPanelGroupWrapperOfTab1"...` and `<p:commandButton execute="mainPanelGroupWrapperOfTab2"` ?

Comment: I tried to add the execute attribute to both the buttons but nothing changes. The parameter is overwritten during the second submission and I get the same error..

Comment: show in your code example one of those overridden fields...

Comment: @Daniel, I've posted an example

Comment: does it work fine if you try session scope bean ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I'd like to avoid session scope.

Comment: Try to see what invalidates the viewscoped bean , try adding `@PostConstruct` method to the bean and add some print outs there... to see when it is being destroyed...

Comment: @Daniel. I've already tried to put some print outs in the constructor but it seems that is never called after the first invocation. Tomorrow I'll try with the postconstructor and let you know.. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel. I've discovered that what invalidates the view is the navigation from one tab to another. That's because, I think, the wizard uses a String to choose the right step so, being not null nor void, it invalidates the current view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, navigating from one page to another, Primefaces wizard, uses a String to identify the tab. Returning the value of this String, which is not null nor void, makes the view bean go out of scope. It is ok when you have a simple form but, if you wanna set some properties not related to a form element during the flow, they get overwritten during the tab changes.
I solved the problem adding to the form an hidden parameter linked to the property I wanted to preserve.

```
<h:inputHidden value="formBean.idToPreserve" id="inputHidden" />
```

Comment: Hi I have the same problem. Can you please give me more details about how you've solved it?

Comment: @loan Hi, I discovered that the if the property you want to set is not related to the state of an element of a form, it gets invalidated from one tab to another.

Comment: @loan My hack was to relate the property to an element of a form using h:inputHidden. It's simply an input field not shown to the user but in this way you succed in preserving the property when you navigate from a tab to another. Hope this helps!